# How to pass variables in Route which has dynamic URL in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to solve in passing a variable value from a main component `(App.js)` to a child component `Attendees.js`. The route is as follows

## App.js

```
<Router>
     ...
     <Route path="/attendees/:userID/:meetingID" component={Attendees} 
      adminUser={this.state.userId}/>} />
</Router>
```

## Attendees.js

```
componentDidMount(){
    const meetingID = this.props.match.params.meetingID
    const adminUser = this.props.adminUser
}
```

I am not able to retrieve the adminUser which passed as props.(adminUser is getting undefined). But I am able to do variables `(meetingID, userID)` encoded in URL.
How can I get the value `adminUser` in child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render an anonymous component and slip the `adminUser` prop in. Don't forget to proxy the route props along as well.

```
<Router>
  ...
  <Route
    path="/attendees/:userID/:meetingID"
    component={routeProps => (
      <Attendees {...routeProps} adminUser={this.state.userId} />
    )} 
  />
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had tried this but i replaced `routeProps` with `props`. didn't work out well.

Comment: Now I am getting another error in console. It is saying --- Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in Attendees (at App.js:110)
    in component (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari You can name it anything really, but route props is what is being passed from the `Route`, so it makes it clear what it is.

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari Different issue, please open a new question. Feel free to link it here.